# Creating relationship between user, type, and type-title table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I was trying to create a proper table relationship for user info tables, but got confused in the end.

Here is the scenario:

```
1. a **user** can have more than one **type**.
2. where the **type** are: founder, member, and crew.
3. for the crew type, it can have more than one **crew_title** ex: Crew Leader, PR Manager, etc.  
4. and a crew-type-user can only have one **crew_title**.
```

These are my tables so far:

```
**user** table:
- user_id (PK)
- email
- password

**type** table:
- type_id (PK)
- type_name

**user_has_type** table:
- user_id (PK)
- type_id (PK)
```

I tried to create the crew_title inside the **type** table, like this:

```
**type** table:
- type_id (PK)
- type_name 
- crew_type_title
```

But I don't know is that the proper way, since there will be so many empty cell, because there will be only 7-10 users who is crew. Any help would be nice:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the relation between the user and the type_title like this:

**user** table:
- user_id (PK)
- email
- password

**type** table:
- type_id (PK)
- type_name

**type_title** table:
- type_title_id (PK)
- type_id
- title

**user_type_title** table:
- user_type_title_id (PK)
- user_id
- type_title_id

```
SELECT U.*, TT.TITLE 
FROM USER U 
    LEFT JOIN USER_TYPE_TITLE UTT ON UTT.USER_ID = U.ID
    LEFT JOIN TYPE_TITLE TT ON TT.TYPE_TITLE_ID = UTT.TYPE_TITLE_ID
```

**EDIT:**

So before inserting, you should detect which type title goes to which user. For example, let's say this is a dashboard screen for your app and you are setting user type titles. On your screen, you will first select a user (user_id),

```
SELECT * FROM USER;
```

and then a type,

```
SELECT * FROM TYPE;
```

and after selecting the type there will be type titles of that type. You will choose the type title from there (type_title_id).

```
SELECT * FROM TYPE_TITLE WHERE TYPE_ID = <selected_typeid_from_ui>;
```

So while inserting the same scenario:

```
INSERT INTO USER_TYPE_TITLE SET USER_ID = <selected_userid_from_ui>, TYPE_TITLE_ID = <selected_typetitleid_from_ui>;
```

Comment: thanks @webmaster, could you please provide an example of select query to display user name and crew-title, so that I can understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new to this.. But whenever I find that a given table I use has one too many null entries, I believe the practice used to solve it is called normalisation of the table 
So how about leaving this as is

**type** table

type_I'd(PK)

type_name

And adding this

**crew_subcategory** table

-User_Id(pk)

-Crew_id(fk)

**crew_title** table

-Crew_Id(PK)

-crew_type title

The crew subcategory table will contain only the entries having a crew title
And the crew title table provides the respective title according to the id. This is similar to what you've used for title and title id

Not sure if this is the best approach. Let me know what you think about it :)

Comment: thanks @Jai Lulla. Do you mean that there will be no relation between **type** table and **crew_title** table?

Comment: Crew_type table contains only entries for type the type crew and not for founder or member.. So there won't be any reason for crew_type to know what is the type of the user...

Answer (score 0):

I thinking:

**user** table:
- user_id (PK)
- email
- password

**type** table:
- type_id (PK)
- type_name

**user_has_type** table:
- user_id (FK) Foreign Key 
- type_id (PK)

**type_title**
  id(PK)
  title_name

**title_has_type**
 title_id(PK)
 type_id(FK) Foreign Key

**title_has_user**
  title_id(PK)
  user_id(FK) Foreign Key

Comment: thanks @Abu Jafar Md. Salah. could you please provide an example of select query to display user name and crew-title, so that I can understand it well.

Comment: Please check this :  SELECT user.UserName, type_title.TitleName FROM user LEFT JOIN type_title ON user.user_id=.type_title.title_id